# change button text in JS/jQuery upon process completion in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am working on jQuery/AJAX code as shown below which calls convert.php script.

```
   jQuery(document).ready(function($)
   {
    $('.go-btn').click(function()
    {   
        let target = $(this).attr('data-id'),
            spanEl = $('.file-name[data-id='+ target +']');

        $.ajax({
            url: 'convert.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {id: target}, //change to what you want
            success: function(res)
            {
                console.log("Tested");
            },
            error: function(res)
            {

            }
        })
    })  
   });
```

In **convert.php** script conversion of mp4 into mp3 is happening. Once the conversion is complete, on console **Tested** is printed.

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what changes I should make in jQuery/AJAX code above so that once the conversion is complete, the button text belonging to the HTML code below gets change to **Completed**

The above jQuery/AJAX code is called on button click. Here is the snippets of HTML code belonging to the button:

**HTML Code:**

```
  <?php  foreach ($programs as $key => $program) {  ?> 
       <tr data-index="<?php echo $key; ?>">
          <td><input type="submit" name="go-button" value="Go" data-id="<?php echo $key; ?>" ></input></td>
       </tr>
  <?php }?>
```

Comment: Why not just update the button text with jQuery with `success`: `$('.go-btn').val('Completed');`

Comment: Where do you want me to update  this ?

Comment: Within `success` - same place as you are writing "tested" to the console.

Comment: like this ?            `success: function(res)
            {
               $('.go-btn').val('Completed');
            },`

Comment: It worked, thanks for the help @MER I have one small question. 

The above HTML code has many rows and each single row has Go button. Once the process is complete for individual row, Go text gets changed to Completed in all rows which is not I want. Go text 
should get changed to completed only to the row which its belong to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a matter of capturing the button that was clicked:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.go-btn').click(function() {
    let target = $(this).attr('data-id'),
      spanEl = $('.file-name[data-id=' + target + ']');
    // Capture the element that received the event
    let btn = this;
    $(btn).val("Converting").prop('disabled', true).css({
      'text-align': 'center',
      'border-color': '#000',
      'width': '120px'
    });
    $.ajax({
      url: 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/80dex',
      method: 'GET', // Change this back to POST
      data: {
        id: target
      }, //change to what you want
      success: function(res) {
        $(btn).val("Completed")
      },
      error: function(res) {
        $(btn).prop('disabled', false).val("Go").removeAttr('style');
      }
    })
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr data-index="1">
  <td>
    <input type="submit" name="go-button" class="go-btn" value="Go" data-id="1"></input>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr data-index="2">
  <td>
    <input type="submit" name="go-button" class="go-btn" value="Go" data-id="2"></input>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr data-index="3">
  <td>
    <input type="submit" name="go-button" class="go-btn" value="Go" data-id="3"></input>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Why did you add  `let btn = this;` ?

Comment: @john Because it's the specific button that was clicked. If you tried to use `this` inside the callback, `this` would point to the request. Javascript is weird like that. You can learn more [in this article](https://medium.com/@anjalisharma0626/what-is-call-site-of-a-function-8e5d9881c49e) or [this book](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/tree/master/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes)

Comment: Make sense and we can use both `GET` and `POST`

Comment: I have one last question. Is there any way we can change the text from **Go** to **Converting** once the conversion is in process ? I have added the following script in my codebase which changes the text from **Go** to **Converting** but it doesn't know anything what is happening in the background. It only changes the text from **Go** to **Converting**

 `$("input[name='go-button']").click( function() {

   // Change the text of the button, and disable
   $(this).val("Converting").attr("disabled", "true").css({'text-align': 'center', 'border-color': '#000', 'width': '120px'});
   
 });`

Comment: @john you can do it in the same handler, I updated the answer

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I have accepted your answer. I will let you know if I have any other question.

Comment: The other thing which I am thinking is when I am open the same webpage on different machine, it should know that file has been completed **(conversion of mp4=>mp3 is done)**. On opening the page on different machine, **Go button text** shows up again belonging to particular file which is not right because that file is already completed .

Comment: @john what if you took care of that in the php side by disabling the buttons beforehand? If you are looking for realtime updates, I'm thinking you might use WebSockets instead. Hard to say without knowing more about your architecture.